# How to get a top left corner of button to be at the centre of the screen in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So basically i have a button and instead of placing it in the centre(horizontally) of the screen i want it a bit off, with its left corner starting in the centre.
Hardcoding margin from one of the sides is not an option.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a `View` and a `Button` in horizontal linear layout, and give equal `layout_weight` to both `View` and `Button`, the  button left cornor will start from center